# Powerful Macros plugin for PhpStorm

Tags: plugins, macros, phpstorm

I want plugin for PhpStorm which can record my actions like this: opening files, changing active window with file content, finding contents etc.
Default Macro doesn't support this actions.
Or I want sources of simple macro plugin. Thanx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such plug-in doesn't exist. Sources for the Macro subsystem are available in the [IntelliJ IDEA Community git repository](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/).

Comment: Sorry, but I don't find Macro subsystem in the IntelliJ IDEA Community git repository

Comment: Start [from here](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/tree/master/platform/platform-impl/src/com/intellij/ide/actionMacro).